# python @classmethod returning 'nonetype'

Tags: python, class-method

new to python here and still working through some growing pains. Due to poor source control management, I lost the original code that had this class method working. My intent here is to get the class method to take inputs from the user and assign those to the attributes to create an object.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, date, name, phone, shells, taps):
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.shells = shells
        self.taps = taps
        self.total = (shells * 100) + (taps * 50)
        swaps = []
        self.swaps = swaps

    @classmethod
    def get_info(cls):
        self.date = input('Enter the date:  ')
        self.name = input('Enter the full name: ')
        self.phone = input("Enter the phone number: ")
        self.shells = input('Enter the number of shells:    ')
        self.taps = input('Enter the number of taps:    ')
```

When I try to call the "newly created object" I get the attribute error 'nonetype'.
I feel like I am close but have yet to get the right combination to get it working. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `classmethod`s return instances of `cls`. Typically they're like factory methods which call `cls(*args, **kwargs)`. Basically you're not actually creating a "newly created object" like you claim. :-) If you remove the `self.` parts and return `cls(date, name, phone, shells, taps)`, you'll see what you expect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. How do you even get that error? If I run `User.get_info()` and input a date, it errors `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` at `self.date =`. You need to provide a [mre] including complete but minimal code, example input, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score -1):

`get_info` should **not** be part of `User`. (Next week you will need to create a user based on data that comes from socket or DB ..)

So collect the input and instantiate a `User` instance.

See below

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, date, name, phone, shells, taps):
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.shells = shells
        self.taps = taps
        self.total = (shells * 100) + (taps * 50)
        swaps = []
        self.swaps = swaps


date = input('Enter the date:  ')
name = input('Enter the full name: ')
phone = input("Enter the phone number: ")
shells = input('Enter the number of shells:    ')
taps = input('Enter the number of taps:    ')

user: User = User(date,name,phone,shells,taps)
```

Comment: It makes total sense as a `@classmethod` if it's intended to create a new `User`. That's what `@classmethod`s are for, alternate constructors. They just need to remove all the `self.`, and end with `return cls(date, name, ...)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think that the class itself (even if @classmethod) is used should not be aware of the way the attributes are fetched. It feels "cleaner". What if we need to create a `User` from DB table?

Comment: @ShadowRanger the intent is indeed to create a new user. I had it working once before and accidentally deleted it. rookie mistake i know.

Comment: @KrysM What if next week the user will have to be created based on data coming from a DB table and later on based on files coming from AWS S3?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Its working now!

Comment: @balderman That would eventually be the goal, yet at present extends beyond the scope of my understanding. (proper instruction is on the horizon)

Comment: I recommend to separate the data collection from the `User` - it will server you in the future. (I understand that you dont see the "full" picture at the moment and its fine ..)